# ElasticSearch - Getting paged result in a nested list (nested pagination)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following Json that describes a country-city (1:n) relation

```
{
    "country": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Country1",
            "city": [
                {"id": 1, "name": "City1"},
                {"id": 2,"name": "City2"}
            ]
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Country2",
            "city": [
                {"id": 3,"name": "City3"},
                {"id": 4,"name": "City4"}
            ]
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Country3",
            "city": [
                {"id": 5,"name": "City5"},
                {"id": 6,"name": "City6"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have loaded it into an ES map with 3 documents of the three countries.
I have added nested property in the city index

```
...
 "city": {
             "type": "nested",
...
```

I want to query all cities and get a paged result.

1. For instance 3 hits will return city1, city2, city3
2. I want to filter by country name

I tried

```
GET /127.0.0.1:9200/country_city/_search
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 2,
    "fields": [
       "city.id", "city.name"
    ]
}
```

and

```
GET /127.0.0.1:9200/country_city/country/_search?_source=false
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "city",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "inner_hits": {
          "sort": "city.id",
          "from": 0,
          "size": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "name",
    "city.id",
    "city.name"
  ]
}
```

But the first returned two 4 cities instead of 2.
(2 countries have 2 cities each)
The second returned all documents(although size is 2 in the request) and in an inner element returned the first 3 cities of each country.

How Can I get a page size of the nested object?
And then progress to the next page?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

**Mappings**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "properties": {
                "country": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "city": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "country",
            "inner_hits": {},
            "query": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "country.city",
                    "query": {
                        "match_all": {}
                    },
                    "inner_hits": {
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 1,
                        "_source": {
                            "includes": ["country.city.name", "country.city.id"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[github bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21312)

[source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)

Thanks

Comment: This actually returns empty array of hits. even when I am clearing the inner query . btw why is the outer object marked as nested also?

Comment: yeah because the other object is also nested. did you ran the mappings i shared, both country and city are nested objects

Comment: I did but my data feeder creates another mapping when it feeds the data (using dynamic mapping). my mapping is of object 'country' that contains 'city'. yours is object with name 'type' that contains 'country' that contains 'city'.

Comment: yeah you have to avoid dynamic mappings, since this is has_many association which always related to nested or parent child relationships. checkout https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/nested.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/parent-child.html. yeah country is of nested as its the array like array of cities inside the countries.

Comment: Thanks. I am always using static mapping but I set dynamic this simple example. Just so I would understand, you recommend changing my data by wrapping country in another object called type and hold one instance in each type object?

Comment: no type is not an object here, root document have country as nested type. type here is just the name of document/mapping type as you can have multiple types in same index. its analogous to table name in sql. i have indexed the same sample document that you have posted with this mapping. take a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping.html